# Image not displaying in Django template

Tags: django

Am working on an existing template, When I change the name of the new image nit does display when I return the pervious image it displays. Is there cache list I can change to do the modification am new to Django.

Original
`<img class="HeaderImage" src="/media/img/logo.png" />`

My update
`<img class="HeaderImage" src="/media/img/logo_1.png" />`

Comment: Does the image exist? How are you serving your files? Have you actually got caching enables? Are you using django's static files?

Comment: Yes the image does exist.In the settings file I have `MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1/media/' does that count as static

Comment: This is normally not how you serve files within Django. Have you tried the tutorial on the Django website?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your Browser and get Data again (Shift + F5)
Make sure the new image exists in the spcified Browser.
 
Clear Cache of your Browser (In the Settings of your Browser)
Close your Browser and reopen it (Works sometimes if Cache is empty but elements still display as bevore [Especially images])

Answer (score 0):

Use the next example, I had the same problem, I just had to modify the source:

```
<img src="{% static "images/final.jpg" %}" alt="Chania" alt="Cinque Terre" width="500" height="200">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.